# How to Prove $n=O(100n+n\sin(n))$

Tags: asymptotics

So I started learning about O notation and got this question

> Prove $n=O(100n+n\sin(n))$.

I found it hard but still tried my best.

\begin{align}
 n&=O(100 n+n \sin(n)),\\
n &\le  c( 100n+n\sin(n)) , \ \ c=1 \\
 n &\le  100n+n\sin(n) \\
1 &\le  100+\sin(n) \\
-99 &\le \sin(n), \ \  N=1.
\end{align}
like I know it looks like piece of cake but $\sin(n)$ made me wonder if it's a right way to solve and prove $O$ notation including $\sin(n)$?

Comment: From $-1\leq \sin n\leq 1,$ deduce:$$99\leq 100+\sin n\leq 101.$$ Multiply by $n$ and note $n<99n.$

Comment: For $n\geq 1$, $n < 99n = 100n - n \le 100n + n\sin n$, since $-1 \le \sin n\le 1$.